# Angular2 sidenav with collapsible list: keeping only one sublist open

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-material

I have a working sidenav demo here using Angular 2, TypeScript, and Material Design components. On the sidenav there is a UL, and the Sites and Users anchors in the UL expand to show their own sub-list.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmzIqaL7pq4oPyT9oV5R?p=preview)

Here's the HTML of the sidenav:

```
<md-sidenav #start mode="over" class="sideDrawer">
    <ul class="sidenav">
      <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="sideNavClick()">Sites</a>
          <div>
            <ul *ngIf="clickedSites" class="sublist">
                <li><a (click)='sideNavAlert()'>All Sites</a></li>
                <li><a>Site Groups</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a (click)="sideNavClickUser()">Users</a>
          <div>
            <ul *ngIf="clickedUsers" class="sublist">
                <li><a (click)="sideNavAlert()" >Add User</a></li>
                <li><a>Edit User</a></li>
                <li><a>Remove User</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a>Lights</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</md-sidenav>
```

This is a very simple implementation of my solution, but my real sidenav will have many more navigation options in the sidenav, and all will have children that need to either be shown or hidden. However, I only want one sublist showing at a time. I don't want to have a boolean for every sublist and use *ngIf to show and hide them, and have some master function in the component that flips the boolean values. I'm hoping for something more lean, but I don't know what's possible with Angular 2 for this. I know I could maybe do a CSS solution, but I would think that would also force me to add and remove classes to each individual list, just like flipping the boolean value for each individual list in my other potential solution.

Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to store the (single) currently open menu in a variable. Whenever an expandable menu item is clicked, either the menu closes (if it was open), or it opens, while the currently open one closes.

The component:

```
export class AppComponent {
    clicked: string = null;

    sideNavClick(clicked: string): void {
        this.clicked = this.clicked == clicked ? null : clicked;
    }

    sideNavAlert(): void {
        alert("sublist item clicked");
    }
}
```

And the template file:

```
<a (click)="sideNavClick('sites')">Sites</a>
<div>
    <ul *ngIf="clicked == 'sites'" class="sublist">...</ul>
</div>

...

<a (click)="sideNavClick('users')">Users</a>
<div>
    <ul *ngIf="clicked == 'users'" class="sublist">...</ul>
</div>
```

As a side note; I would definitely recommend creating an array in the component, based on which the menu would be automatically generated to avoid having to type all the possibilities.

[Here is the modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wgx3uOf9nMa0FLNb5Y3Q?p=preview).

Comment: That seems like a great solution to my problem. Thanks